# Let a dll call a .exe function by sending a pointer

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, dll

This question looks like one I asked before, except that I now know that you can't call the main function from a global object. So this code doesn't work with main. But why does it fail with other functions as well?

This is the code.

**.exe**
main.cpp

```
#include "dll_class.h"
#include <iostream>
int my_main(void)
{
    std::cout << "Enter the my_main code.\n";
    std::getchar();
}

DllClass object(my_main);
int main(void)
{
    std::cout << "Enter the main code.\n";
    std::getchar();
}
```

**.dll**
dll_class.h

```
#include "platform.h"
#include <iostream>
class DLL_API DllClass //DLL_API is just a macro for import and export.
{
public:
    DllClass(int(*main)(void))
    {
        std::cout << "Start application.\n";
        platform = new Platform(main);
    }
    ~DllClass(void)
    {
        delete platform;
    }
private:
    Platform* platform;
};
```

platform.h

```
class DLL_API Platform
{
public:
    Platform(main_t main_tp);
    ~Platform(void){}
};
```

platform.cpp

```
#include "platform.h"
#include "Windows.h"
#include <iostream>

HHOOK hookHandle;
int(*main_p)(void);//This will hold a the main function of the the .exe.
LRESULT CALLBACK keyHandler(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

DWORD WINAPI callMain(_In_  LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    std::cout << "Calling the main function.\n";
    main_p();
    return 0;
}

Platform::Platform(int(*main_tp)(void))
{
    main_p = main_tp;
    CreateThread(NULL, 0, callMain, NULL, 0, NULL);
    std::cout << "Setting hooks.\n";
    hookHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, keyHandler, NULL, 0);
    std::cout << "Enter message loop.\n";
    MSG message;
    while(GetMessage(&message, (HWND)-1, 0, 0) != 0){
        TranslateMessage( &message );
        DispatchMessage( &message );
    }
}

LRESULT CALLBACK keyHandler(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    std::cout << "Inside the hook function.\n" << std::endl;
    return CallNextHookEx(hookHandle, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

It runs great, till a certain moment.
This is the output.

```
Start application.  
Setting hooks.  
Calling the main function.  
Enter message loop.  
Inside the hook function. (A lot of times of course).
```

but it never says:

```
Enter the my_main code.
Enter the main code.
```

Is it impossible to let dll call a exe function?

Comment: I think your problem has less to do with a pointer to the function in the EXE, and more to do with threads.  You might also have violations of the One Definition Rule.  Are application and library using the same compile options?

Comment: Where is `main_p` declared in your `Platform` class?

Comment: @Tony: He showed that code, it is a global in platform.cpp

Comment: @BenVoigt I overlooked it. Sorry

Comment: I would definitely add a `std::endl;` or `std::flush` to the output, since if the thread doesn't do that, it may well never output the actual output.

Comment: @Mats Petersson: I tried std::endl, but it doesn't work. Had no idea it made any difference.

Comment: @BenVoigt: The compile options are the same, so that is probably not the problem. But if I made a mistake with the threads, what could it be?

Comment: It may not be related but Can you try removing `std::getchar()` ? or creating a file other than writing to stdout ?

Comment: Yes, I would definitely remove the `std::getchar()`. I'm absolutely sure that you can call a function via a pointer in the main executable - as I answered elsewhere with exactly the same question. I would set a breakpoint in "my_main" and see where that gets you.

Comment: @Mats Petersson I forgot to remove it before showing the code to you. The breakpoint is never reached, in main and my_main. Might sending a message and let the message loop continue make any difference?

Comment: Right, the fact that it's never reached is curious to me. Then set a breakpoint at the previously visible point, and step through the code - that would be `callMain`.

Comment: @Mats Petersson: I get `Call stack location` `test.exe!my_main()`. But when I click to show the disassembly, the page has no code at all.

Comment: What are your registers showing - I'm afraid my Linux systems won't compile Windows code, so you'll have to step through the assembler code step by step - but it sounds like you land "somewhere wrong".

Comment: @Mats Petersson: Thats the problem. I actually didn't noticed it, but the Disassembly is completely empty. I've never seen this before.

Comment: I see `my_main` have no declaration. does it have any thing to do with it ? or it looks like somehow are you having a `my_main` function that is empty

Comment: You have two threads using std::cout without mutex protection.

Comment: That should cause a different problem like string will get messed up by other threads that are writing to std::cout. but it will never deadlock writing in stdout. and also disassembly will not get empty for this

Comment: @Mats Petersson: My mistake, there is some disassembly: `jc_main:
000D1F15 FF 25 D8 D2 0E 00 jmp dword ptr [__mep@?jc_main@@$$FYAHXZ (0ED2D8h)]`, after that it says `disassembly cannot be displayed in run mode` and than it becomes blank. The other threads start running automatically.

Comment: @Neel Basu The std::stream code uses pointers to a buffer to keep track of text.  If two threads update the pointers at the same time, one text can easily get lost.

Comment: @brian beuning: I've tried it with a mutex since the last comment, but that didn't help. Though useful to know, I didn't expect it solve to the problem, since the breakpoint wasn't triggered.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is still the same as the one I gave to your other question. Your `Platform` constructor is hung. The loop termination conditions are never met, so the constructor never returns. And the `main` function cannot run until all global objects have been constructed.

**Update**: The above discussion was why `Enter the main code` never prints.

If you step through your `my_main` function, you'll see the problem with `Enter the my_main code`: The calls to `cout` and `getchar` are ignored. That's because the order of constructions of global objects in different translation units is unspecified. In the main executable, the `object` global object is being constructed first, which means that the `cin` and `cout` objects may not be fully constructed. That's why `cout` can't print and why `getchar` cannot read.

Comment: Then how it prints `Calling the main function` ?

Comment: @Raymond Chen: I've send the my_main function as pointer. The main function at the bottom of main.cpp is not used this time.

Comment: @Raymond Chen: But the breakpoint isn't triggered as well. It should be triggered, shouldn't it? And without a disassembly I'm completely clueless.

Comment: Then step through the `callMain` function. Note that even if you get this to "work", you are relying on unspecified behavior, so it's not a good plan.

Comment: @Raymond Chen: I have a comment above that says what happens when I do that. But I also think that I should look for an alternative. I don't think I'm able to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

Surely, the CORRECT thing to do here is to construct the `object` inside `main`. If needed, pass in `my_main` to the object. But this will solve all of the "trying to use something before it has been constructed".

The key here (which I only gather from reading the comments on the other answer) is that the `cout` object is not "the same one" for the main executable and the DLL. This leads to issues with calling things that do `cout` before you have entered `main` [which I tried to explain in the previous question too - the C runtime library needs to initialize certain things, and that happens in an unspecified order before `main` is called].

Comment: I thought that you only meant the main itself, not other objects. Initializing the object in `main` was plan B, but that went against the guidelines I wanted to use. But you can't have everything I guess.

Comment: On Windows, if you link without using DLL then you get multiple copies of globals.  If you link everything using DLL then you should not.  In MSVC the option is in project properties / C/C++ / Code Generation / Runtime Library.

Comment: It was already on /MDd.