# Calling function from DLL

Tags: c++, dll-injection

Is it possible to call a known function (We know the function type, name and argumets) inside a program using DLL Injection?

For example there is following function in my program:

```
void func(string text)
{
    cout << text << endl;
}
```

How to call it from a DLL?

Comment: function func is in DLL and you want to call it from outside  or is it outside DLL and you want to call it from DLL?

Comment: No, i want to call func that is in an .exe using DLL

Comment: What do you mean by `is in an .exe`? You wrote the function, wrote the `main` function and created an .exe? And you want to use that function from inside an already compiled .exe? That's impossible.

Comment: you have to export this function just as if it was dll

Comment: Usually it is the other way around, an `exe` calls functions inside `dll`, if you trying to do the reverse, please state so

Comment: @pitorus i think he has no control over the EXE

Comment: OP has stated so already: "No, i want to call func that is in an .exe using DLL"

Comment: Is it impossible even if i know the function adress?

Comment: He wrote it in the comment, not the question, and also he stating `DLL injection`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15311934/let-a-dll-call-a-exe-function-by-sending-a-pointer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to call an arbitrary function given only prototype and it's address in memory, however you have to be able to call it on the other process address space (this can be done by linking to shared library or attaching debugger)

```
typedef int func(void);
func* f = (func*)0xabcd123;
int i = f(); // execute
```

However I have tried also copy the code to executable part of memory and running it with something like this:

```
  char code[] = {0x55,0x48,0x89,0xe5,0x89,0x7d,0xfc,0x48,0x89,0x75,
                 0xf0,0xb8,0x2a,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xc9,
                 0xc3,0x00};    // it is just compiled: return  42 
                                // (with prologue, etc)
  void *buf;

  /* copy code to executable buffer */    
  buf = mmap (0,sizeof(code),PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC,
              MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON,-1,0);
  memcpy (buf, code, sizeof(code));

  /* run code */
  int i = ((int (*) (void))buf)();
  printf("the code returned: %d\n", i);
```

so if you know the size of code to execute it looks as possible.